# pavucontrol, pulseaudio "home directory not accessible: permission denied"

Tags: permissions, pulseaudio, root, spotify, pavucontrol

Within the Ubuntu 14.04 GUI terminal (using TightVNC java viewer from a Mac), I can't seem to get out of root# and enter the user$ directory in order to start pulseaudio and/or pavucontrol...

- pulseaudio => `This program not intended to be run as root` and `Failed to acquire autospawn lock`
- pavucontrol => `home directory not accessible: permission denied`

How do I get out of root from the GUI? `exit` just closes the terminal.

Comment: How did you start the gnome-terminal?